# How to get text from <textarea> in JMeter

Tags: html, jmeter, textarea, extract

In Jmeter one of my HTML Requests contains *textarea* in Response Body:

```
...
    <textarea name="responseABC" id="responseABC" rows="10">
        {
           "response" : {
              "attribute_list" : [ {
                 "type" : "string_list",
                 "name" : "FamilyName",
                 "values" : [ {
                    "value" : "John"
                 } ]
              }
          }
        }
    </textarea>
...
```

I need to extract the text from that *textarea* to send it as a parameter in a next request.
I tried using

- CSS Selector Extractor (CSS Selector Expression: "textarea[id="responseABC"]")
- XPath Extractor (XPath Query: "//textarea[@id='responseABC']")

but these return the whole element.

Is there any way I can get only the text itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there with XPath, all you need is to add [`/text()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev) in order to get matched node(s) text node child(ren)

```
//textarea[@id='responseABC']/text()
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xpath-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you! This works. Just to note I had to use tolerant parser in XPath Extractor as well.